# Python pandas, errors using .str.contains to search dataframe column for substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, contains

I'd appreciate any help you could offer on this issue using python 2.7, pandas 0.22, and easygui 0.98.1.

I'm trying to load a csv into pandas, assign column names from a user-chosen list using easygui (returns as a list of strings, I think) and search in a certain column of the dataframe for a substring.

```
import easygui as eg
import pandas as pd

# define vars_vars from choices of imagej outputs
vars_vars = eg.multchoicebox
            (msg="\n\n\n\nPlease highlight variables included in ImageJ analysis:",
             title="IF Analysis - 2017",
             choices=["integrated density", "mean", 
                      "mean grey value", "area fraction"])

# add required imagej columns for later processing
vars_vars.insert(0, "label")
vars_vars.insert(0, "#")

#User input for csv file
file = eg.fileopenbox()

# load into dataframe using pandas and assign columns using chosen variables
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, names=None)
df.columns = vars_vars

# Search 'label' column for certain substring
df[df['label'].str.contains('substring')]
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/.PyCharmCE2017.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 61, in <module>
    df[df['label'].str.contains('nsv')]
  File "C:\Users\User\Miniconda2\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3614, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I tried goolging it, and found these fixes

```
df['label'] = df['label'].map(str)
df['label'] = df['label'].astype(str)
df['label'] = df['label'].astype(baseline)
```

and variations of those where I call the entire dataframe rather than df['label'].

However, these all result in no error following pass of that fix line, but invariably returns a similar error as previously when I do the .str.contains line which states dataframe object has no attribute map (for .map(str)) or str (for .astype(x)) lines.

---

```
print type(df['label'])
print df.dtypes
print df['label'].head()
print (df['label'].info())
print type(df['label'][0])
```

returns

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

#                      int64
label                 object
integrated density     int64
dtype: object

                                        label
0         nc4_al1_I+pP_4x_contra_ctx_blue.tif
1        nc4_al1_I+pP_4x_contra_ctx_green.tif
2         nc4_al1_I1+pP_4x_contra_ctx_red.tif
3          nc4_al1_I+pP_4x_contra_hc_blue.tif
4         nc4_al1_I+pP_4x_contra_hc_green.tif

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 695 entries, 0 to 694
Data columns (total 1 columns):
(label,)    695 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 5.5+ KB
None

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shon/.PyCharmCE2017.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 67, in <module>
    print type(df['label'][0])
  File "C:\Users\User\Miniconda2\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2137, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
  File "C:\Users\User\Miniconda2\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2181, in _getitem_multilevel
    loc = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\User\Miniconda2\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 2072, in get_loc
    loc = self._get_level_indexer(key, level=0)
  File "C:\Users\User\Miniconda2\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 2362, in _get_level_indexer
    loc = level_index.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\User\Miniconda2\envs\test2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2527, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help you guys could offer.

---

UPDATE:

Turns out the issue was having a multiindex dataframe.

```
df.columns.map(''.join).str.strip()
```

Resulted in changing the column into a series upon printing its type, which enabled me to correctly .str.contains the data.

Comment: What does type(df['label']) return?

Comment: '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' -- Thanks for your help

EDIT: I did df.dtypes and got the following output:
`#                      int64

label                 object

integrated density     int64
dtype: object`

Comment: Yes,  that is correct, your df['label'] is not a series, .str accessor works on series.  What does df['label'].head() return include that result in your question.  Thanks.

Comment: Updated. Thank you. Do you suggest I try and convert the columns into series?

Comment: Also, so `print(df['labels'].info())`.  You have a strangely structured dataframe. I am trying to really understand what exactly you have. Normally, type(df['label']) returns pd.Series.   But yours does not.  So, you have something non-standard.

Comment: As far as I know I haven't done anything outside of documentations I've seen, I just loaded a .csv file without column headers and added them manually from a list. Clearly, I'm new to pandas, but confused how I strayed so far off the path.

Updated. It returns
`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 695 entries, 0 to 694
Data columns (total 1 columns):
(label,)    695 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 5.5+ KB
None`

Thanks

Comment: It returns an error. I have updated the OP with it at the bottom.

Comment: I think you have a multiindex dataframe column with an empty index.  `df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join).str.strip()` now print(type(df['label']))

Comment: That did it! Got `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: And `print(df['label']).str.contains('substring')` results in an output of Falses rather than just the rows containing that substring, but that's something I can work with. Thanks for your help-- I'm still a little confused as to how we got here, I'm assuming I setup the dataframe incorrectly, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Post your answer as a proper *answer*, not inside the question. (Also plain "Using .str.contains to search dataframe column for substring" is a better title. Everybody here has "trouble".)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output from `type(df['label']).info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> 
RangeIndex: 695 entries, 0 to 694 
Data columns (total 1 columns): 
(label,) 695 non-null object 
dtypes: object(1) memory usage: 5.5+ KB None
```

It appears as if the column from this dataframe is a tuple with an empty element, which indicates a multiindex column heading where the second level is empty.

I recommend first we try to fix the `pd.read_cv` prevent the creation of a multiindex.  However, using:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join).str.strip()
```

Will flatten that multiindex column header to a single level column index and create a `pd.Series` datatype for df['label'] then allowing the usage of string accessor and `contains`.

Comment: @SK If this solution helped you, you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) by checking this answer.  Thank you.